# How to get previous record information

Tags: oracle

I need to retrieve the columns Random_1, Random_2, Random_3
My other table is joining data off the date key 9/25/2016.  I also need to see Random_1, Random_2,Random_3 looking at the 9/22/2016.  I want to know how to say from my join on date key whatever the date may be show me the previous record information. 
 Dates are dates and I am using Oracle
(The dates will change)

How can do this?
[See link for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdbmH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To pull Random_1 for the previous date, you would use the `LAG()` function, like so:

```
select ... ,  lag(t1.random_1) over (order by t1.date_key), .....
from  table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.date_key = t2.date_key
...
```

(and same for the other columns). Note that the result of `LAG()` will, of course, be `NULL` for the earliest row - since there is no "previous" value. If you want something else for the first row, wrap everything within a `COALESCE()`.

Also, if you have `id`'s of some kind and you join by `id` as well, then you don't want to mix together dates for different id's. The `LAG()` functions (and almost all other analytic functions) allows you to `partition by id` in addition to ordering by date. You can read the definition and examples in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions075.htm#SQLRF00652).

Comment: the `LAG` and `LEAD` analytic functions have two additional optional parameters: `offset`, and `default`, so there's no need to use `COALESCE()`, just provide the two additional parameters when calling it: `lag(t1.random_1, 1, 'default value') ...`

Comment: Good point @Sentinel, I usually leave `lag()` as `NULL` in those cases but you are absolutely right, they do have the "default value" option in case it's needed (and the offset is not needed, the default is 1 anyway, but it IS needed if you need to give a "default value" because it must be the fourth argument, it can't be the third...) Just not "top of mind" for me since I don't use the default value!  {:-)

Comment: there is no fourth argument, unless you count differently than I do.

Comment: err... third and second (instead of fourth and third). By the way, thank you for the edit - but I re-edited, I linked to LAG specifically.

Comment: I considered linking [`LAG()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm#SQLRF00652) in your fist sentance to the LAG documentation in addtion to linking to the general [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) documentation.