# Getting Null with Lag function

Tags: oracle

I am still getting a Null. Can you take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong? My lag value is Null and it should be zero based how it's listed in the table. Here is my code - see link for output of tables and my results[image]

```
SELECT T1.ACCOUNT_NBR,
       T1.CUSTOMER_KEY,
       T2.RANDOM_1,
       T2.RANDOM_2,
       T2.RANDOM_3,
       LAG(T2.RANDOM_3, 1) OVER (ORDER BY T2.CALENDAR_KEY)AS LAGVALUE
FROM   T1
       JOIN T2
         ON T1.CUSTOMER_KEY = T2.CUSTOMER_KEY
            AND T1.ACCOUNT_NBR = T2.ACCOUNT_NBR
            AND T1.WO_CHECKED_IN_DT_KEY = T2.CALENDAR_KEY
```

Comment: Please format your question properly, and provide some sample data with which we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need `LAG(T2.RANDOM_3, 1, 0)` - please go back to your earlier thread and read CAREFULLY what was said there. The third argument,  `0`, is the "default value" to be used when there's no "previous" row, but you left it out. Also, opening a new thread for a question you asked already is inappropriate; it would be better if you would voluntarily remove (cancel, delete) this thread, at least after you fix your query and you see it works. I will mark it for closing anyway.

Comment: OP is just asking for clarification on answer to her question in [How to get previous record information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431349/how-to-get-previous-record-information)

Comment: There is a previous row.  The number in random3 is actually a zero.

Comment: What comes before the first row?